# CSS - Flow break issue

Tags: html, css, overflow

I explained my problem in the question details. I am sorry for the question title, I couldn't find anything clearer.

I want my all lines line up (including third and fourth, etc), but they don't. My img doesn't break the lines, so I think I should clear the left part, but I can't figure it out.

What's missing?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="comments-comments">
        <div id="comment-1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="user-img-sub"><img class="user-avatar-sub"
                                                   src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-17.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="user-name-sub"><a href="">John Doe</a></div>

                </li>
                <li id="comment-1-itself">Hello Stackoverflow! I hope I can get an answer for this question! As you can
                    see, starting from the third
                    line, I am experiencing this flow issue with CSS.
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.comments-comments {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 0 20px 10px;
}

#comment-1 ul {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

#comment-1 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.user-avatar-sub {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
}

.user-name-sub {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#comment-1-itself {
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show with an image the expected result?

Comment: Of course. The word "experiencing" starts from left but I want it to be lined up with the comment (first & second lines). http://i.imgur.com/kUjlm1R.png

Comment: This is what I see http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/EajqaP ... is not the same what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason you have all that in `li` tags? That'll make it a bit messy to fix. Basically; you've caused this by 1) making the items display inline and 2) floating the image.

Comment: @ianaya89, no, it isn't. I sketched it, take a look :) http://sketchtoy.com/63762959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I added padding to the comment itself.
`padding: 90px;`
and changed the `li`s to be `display: block;`

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9wcs3nu2/

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation, but my rep is currently 6. I really thank you, but there is nothing I can do for now. :(

Answer (score 1):

Tamer, line up against the left? or inline i.e. one after another?

I assume you are asking for them line up left:

```
#comment-1 ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

#comment-1 ul li {
    width: 100%; // you can make then the same width as parent elements
    position: relative; // don't need float if you make them the same width
    float: left;
    // list-style-type: none; // would place this in ul above
    // display: inline; // display inline would collapse borders so use use display block or inline-block
}
```

if you are looking for them line up next to each other then:

```
#comment-1 ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

#comment-1 ul li {
    width: 25%; // you can make then the same width as parent elements
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    // list-style-type: none; // would place this in ul above
    // display: inline; // display inline would collapse borders so use inline-block
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, JonnieJS's answer solved the issue. I acquired a new point of view, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

try Assigning a new div to the both li

```
 <div class="image">
            <li>
                <div class="user-img-sub">
                <img class="user-avatar-sub" src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-17.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </li>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
            <li>
                <div class="user-name-sub"><a href="">John Doe</a></div>
            </li>

            <li id="comment-1-itself">
                Hello Stackoverflow! I hope I can get an answer for this question! As you can
                see, starting from the third
                line, I am experiencing this flow issue with CSS.
            </li>
            </div>
```

[fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rq2a5z3h/)